# For an integrable function $f$, the measure of the set $\{x: |f(x)|=a \}$ is zero for all but countably many $a's$

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ is a probability space and $f$ is integrable function. Then, is it true that $\mu \{ \omega: |f(w)|=\alpha\}=0$ for all but countably many $\alpha$ ? \

Comment: Just for being sure, do you mean by integrable that $\int_{\Omega} |f| \Bbb{d} \mu < \infty$? If this is the case, then the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean by integrability. Also the measure is probability measure, I have modified my question as pointed out by Mike.

Comment: I suspect something like $∞ > ∫_Ω |f| ≥ \sum_{\alpha ∈ \text{im}f} \alpha \mu(|f| = \alpha) $, and a sum of uncountably many terms is finite iff all but countably many are zero.

Comment: 2 minutes. $ $ $ $

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't depend on integrability of $f$. Measurability suffices.
Let 
$$ A_n = \{ a\in [0,+\infty] : \mu(|f|=a)>1/n \}$$
Then the cardinality of $A_n$ is at most $n$.
And $\cup_{n\geq 1} A_n$ is the set of $a$'s for which $\mu(|f|=a)$ is strictly positive.

Remark: The result  also holds for any $\sigma$-finite measure space.

Comment: Why is the cardinality of $A_n$ at most $n$?

Comment: @Adam For a probability measure the sum of measures of disjoint sets is at most 1

Comment: Ah I see! Awesome proof!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that there exists an uncountable set $A$ such that, if $a\in A$, then $\mu\left(\{\omega\in\Omega\Big{|}|f(\omega)|=a \}\right)>0$. For every $n\in\mathbb N$, set $A_n$ to be the set of $a\in A$ such that $$\frac{1}{n}\leq\mu\left(\{\omega\in\Omega\Big{|}|f(\omega)|=a \}\right)<\frac{1}{n-1},$$ then $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n=A$. Since the $A_n$ are countably many and $A$ is uncountable, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $A_N$ is uncountable. Therefore, we can find $\varepsilon>0$ and a sequence $(a_m)$ in $A_N$, such that $a_m>\varepsilon$ for all $m\in\mathbb N$.

Set $$B_m=\{\omega\in\Omega\Big{|}|f(\omega)|=a_m \}.$$ We then compute $$\int_X|f|\,d\mu\geq\sum_{m\in\mathbb N}\int_{B_m}|f|\,d\mu=\sum_{m\in\mathbb N}\int_{B_m}a_m\,d\mu>\sum_{m\in\mathbb N}\varepsilon\mu(B_m)\geq\sum_{m\in\mathbb N}\frac{\varepsilon}{N}=\infty,$$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Oh Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $X$ be a measure space such that $\mu(X)>0$, consider $Y=\bigcup_{a\in R}X_a$ where $(X_a,\mu_a)$ is isomorphic to $\mu_a$, consider $f:Y\rightarrow R$ whose restriction to $X_a$ is the constant function $a$.